# Converting .xlsb to .xlsx using pandas changes dates to random numbers

Tags: python, excel, pandas, converters

I have a .xlsb document that I'm converting to .xlsx using this:

```
df = read_excel('excels/TEF.xlsb, engine = 'pyxlsb')

df.to_excel('.\excels\TEF.xlsx')
```

Conversion(albeit slow) works for everything except dates.

[image: .xlsx and .xlsb files side by side]

Left side is the converted .xlsx file, right side is the original .xlsb file.

As you can see the converted file has random numbers instead of dates.

Any ideas why this happens, and how can I convert .xlsx file to .xlsb file using python/pandas or any other library?

Comment: Those are not random numbers but non-formatted Excel dates: [number of days elapsed since January 1, 1900](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487). Format columns as dates and then compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "random numbers" are days since 01.01.1900. You wil have to convert them after loading the xlsb.